# ejs variable not displaying username

Tags: javascript, variables, ejs

I have this script that I am trying to use to get a username displayed however it is not working. The script works when I just use <%= userName %> but I need it to check if the user is defined before displaying the username or else the page will not load.

```
Username <% if(typeof userName!='undefined'){
      userName
    } %>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this has me at a loss..

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out for anyone else trying to learn this is how I am checking for if the variable userName is undefined and if it is i set it to 'undefined'

```
<% if (userName==='undefined' ) %> { %>
    <%= userName='undefined' %>
        } %>
```